# Insert a component between the search box and the drop down menu in AutoComplete (antd)

Tags: javascript, react-native, frontend, antd

I am doing a component that will have some options that are being laid between the seach box and the drop down menu.

For now I have done this:

```
export default function SearchBoxEvents() {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState<
    { value: string; label: JSX.Element }[]
    >([]);
    const handleSearch = (input: string) => {
        let res: { value: string; label: JSX.Element }[] = [];
        if (!input) {
            res = [];
        } else {
            //this is just a placeholder
            res = ["event 1", "event 2", "event 3"]
            .filter((event) => true)
            .map((event) => ({
                value: event,
                label: <span>Some icon {event}</span>
            }));
        }
        setOptions(res);
    };
    return (
        <AutoComplete
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        options={options}
        >
                <Input.Search size="large" placeholder="to be replaced" />
                <p>
                    "example text"
                </p>
        </AutoComplete>
    );
}
```

This is resulting in this

[image: What I currently have]

But imagine I want to add some text, for example "example text" between the search box and the drop down, if I do this

```
return (
    <AutoComplete
    onSearch={handleSearch}
    options={options}
    >
            <Input.Search size="large" placeholder="to be replaced" />
            <p>
                "example text"
            </p>
    </AutoComplete>
);
```

Then it breaks :c . Does somebody knows how to add text ( not a place holder, additional text)